# Gigabit ethernet running at 10 BaseT speed

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

I have FreeNAS running a SMB file server which I am accessing from Windows, Linux and macOS. File transfer speeds from Windows and macOS are great, around 100MB/sec. File transfer speed to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS is only 5.4MB/sec, which is slower than 100BaseT, and is probably 10BaseT.

I have run ifconfig/ethtool on my Ubuntu box, and it shows a speed of 1000BaseT Full Duplex, and ifconfig on FreeNAS box shows link speed and speed of 1GBit ???!!!

I believe both cards in both machines are Realtek 8169 PCI cards...

Any help much appreciated. I have restarted both machines and I am still getting the same speed...

Answer (score -1):

Just so you know, I tried another cable and got 10MB/sec, but switched back to the old cable under macOS and got Gigabit. Rebooting into Ubuntu also gave me Gigabit, and I still have gigabit every OS I launch !!!